# How to characterize the inequality relation?

Tags: inequality, relations, order-theory, ordered-fields

I'm reading Rudin's real analysis where he defines what an order on a set $S$ is:

**An order** on $S$ is a relation, denoted by $<$, with the following two properties:

1) If $x,y \in S$, then one and only one of the statements: $x = y, x < y, y < x$ is true.

2) If $x,y,z \in S$ and $x < y$ and $y < z$ then $x < z$

Later, he defines the concept ordered field:

**An ordered field** is a field $F$ which is also an ordered set, such that:

1) If $x,y,z \in F$ and $y < z$ , then $x + y < x + z$

2) If $x,y \in F$ and $0 < x, 0 <y$, then $0 <xy$

In all the proofs that follow, he never mentions that he means that $a < b$ is the usual order relation (for example $2.3 < 3$), but all the properties of this usual order relation can be proven from the definitions he provided.

So my question is:

Does this mean that this relation is unique, given the properties in the definition? Can I assume that this is the order relation that I'm familiar with, or is there another relation that can be defined on such a field that satisfies those properties (so in fact I'm asking whether this relation is unique).

More concrete, I'm interested where the field is either $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: please check my edit (are you Dutch maybe?: 2,3 instead of 2.3).

Comment: Yes I'm dutch haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an alternative (and equivalent) route to define an order on a field.

Actually it is enough to state that a set $P\subset F$ exists such that:

- $\{-P,\{0\},P\}$ is a partition of $F$ (here $-P:=\{-x\mid x\in P\}$)
- $\forall x,y\in P\left[x+y\in P\wedge xy\in P\right]$

Then the relation $<$ can be defined as: $$x<y\iff y-x\in P$$

If you start with the other definition then $P$ is exactly the set $\{x\in F\mid 0<x\}$.

Here letter "P" associates with "positive".

In this light your question can be reworded as: is $P$ necessarily unique in this?

If we are dealing with field  $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb Q$) then the answer is yes.

It starts with proving that $1\in P$.

If we assume that $1\notin P$ then we arrive at $1=(-1)(-1)\in P$ and a contradiction is found.

Then $\{1,2=1+1,\dots\}\subseteq P$.

Then (after properly defining) $\mathbb Q_+\subseteq P$.

And finally (after properly defining) $\mathbb R_+= P$.